# HTML input validation message support lackign in IE and Safari

Tags: html, validation, internet-explorer, input, safari

Why don't all validation messages show at the same time for input elements? I use the onsubmit function on all my forms. Also I have a `required` attribute combined with pattern in some of my fields. I was wondering how all messages can show `onSubmit`?

My second problem is the number input type. My fields have different `min` `max` and `step` values. For example here is one of the fields:

```
<td><input type="number" name="frm_srpr" id="frm_srpr" min="0" max="100" step="4" style="width:50px" placeholder="%" /></td>
```

In Firefox and Chrome I will get this message if I enter number `23`:

> Please select a valid value. The two nearest valid values are 24 and 28.

or if I enter letter `A`:

> Please enter a number.

However if I try this in IE or Safari, my message will be next if I enter 23:

> You must enter a valid value.

or in Safari:

> Enter a valid value.

Obviously this description is not enough for the user. I'm wondering how I can fix this problem in IE and Safari? I tried to put a title attribute, but nothing shows on the screen. Seems that title will work only if field is `required`.